# I want my label disappear on the left and appear on the right on swipe

Tags: ios, animation, swipe

I have a view with

- `UIScrollView` -> image view
- `UILabel`

I add a swipe gesture on my `ScrollView` to go to the next image. It works.

My label is the title of my image.
When i swipe, i want my label disappear on the left and appear on the right and set the new title.

Do I need 2 different labels?
How can I animate my label?

Comment: learn how swipe gesture works

Answer (score 0):

Make your label the subview of your scrollView.  Then it will scroll when your image does.

Comment: My image changes but doesn't move to the left or to the right, so if i put my label in the scroll view, it will do the same.
I think my swipe is not animated...but recognized. Do you know why?

Comment: Why do you need a swipe gesture if you have a scroll view (or vice versa)?  I'm assuming you want a fresh label under every image.  I'd view the wwdc video at: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/  Look for the session entitled "Advanced ScrollView Techniques"  You'll need an Apple developer ID (which is free, I believe)

Comment: I need a swipe gesture because i have a zoom into my scroll view.
When i tap once, i hide my label, and i can zoom into my image View.

Comment: My label is read in a Json. Is there a link with the delay to swipe?

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations^{ label.frame = leftOutsideView;} completion^(BOOL finished){ label.frame = rightOutsideView; label.text = newCaption; [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations^{ label.frame = originalPlace;}];}];
```

(This is pseudo code)
Try to use animations in that context, it looks good.

Comment: I do that, it works, thanks, but i want move my text when i swipe (here, there is a duration)..